# How to install Zend Framework 2.2 on Windows?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I did my research, this is what I understand:

1. Download zipball
2. Configure `php.ini` (includ_path)
3. Add Zend's bin directory path to PATH
4. And use `zf` command to create projects

My problem is I can't find zf.bat inside bin (Yes, I did download zipball, using this [link](https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-2.2.0/ZendFramework-minimal-2.2.0.zip)). There's no `zf.bat`, this is how my `bin` looks like:

[image]

My Question:

> Did I download wrong zip? If so where can I get the right one? I've tried downloading all zips from [zend website](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest).

These questions were helpful to me:

1. [How to install Zend Framework on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857002/how-to-install-zend-framework-on-windows)
2. [Installing Zend Framework After Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497257/installing-zend-framework-after-xampp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501345/cant-find-zf-bat-in-zend-framework-download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no zf.bat in Zend Framework 2 (for now anyway), that's in Zend Framework 1.

You will want to download the skeleton application here: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

Also see: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html to see how they are using composer to setup a new project based on the skeleton, rather than using the old zf.bat.

You can also check out ZFTool which is a new utility for managing ZF2: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool

Comment: I installed Composer, runs fine from command line. But when I run 
`php composer.phar self-update` and
`php composer.phar install`, it says `Could not open input file: composer.phar`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: if "php composer.phar" gives you that error, it either isn't installed right, or it isn't in your path. Either way, that's going to be a separate composer issue, not related to the Zend Framework zf.bat question. You may want to post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest of all methods is to:

1. Install [GitHub for Windows](http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHubSetup.exe).
2. Then open `Git Shell` and run following line:

> git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
>   --recursive

That's it.